# SQLite On Host w/ FTP Only

Tags: database, sqlite, web-hosting

Can I put a SQLite database on a host that I only have FTP access to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, an SQLite database is just a file, and FTP is File Transfer Protocol. You will be able to put the database on the server, and get it back.

If you can execute programs, such as cgi scripts, on the server, those programs may be able to access the database as well, depending on how your host restricts the script/program.

Comment: I've been trying to read up on this stuff.  I tried to make a .db file in the sqlite3 command line but I cant seem to find the file.

Comment: The database is created in the current directory (unless you specify a full path name). So, if you are in your home directory (cd ~), typing "sqlite3 mydatabase.db" in your shell will make a database in your home directory. You might need to create a table in the database before SQLite actually writes anything to the file.